# Stargazer removing more covariates than specified

Tags: r, stargazer

I am using the stargazer package in R markdown to produce a table of regression output into a pdf document. I have fixed effects dummies that I would like to remove. "a", "b",... are these dummies.

```
stargazer(one_yr, two_yr, three_yr)
```

The above code produces a table including all of the covariates. [Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jnmp1.jpg)

To remove the fixed effects, I try to add the option  `omit = c("a", "b", "c", ...)`, but this results in the following. Note that almost all of the other covariates were omitted as well.
[trying to omit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFoxY.jpg)

Any ideas why this may be happening, or how to fix it? I want to include all other covariates except "a", "b", ... Thanks!

Comment: Note that you shouldn’t use ‘stargazer’, because [‘stargazer’ is an utterly atrocious package](https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/6o9v9h/whats_your_favorite_relatively_obscure_r_package/dkgw9q1/). Use ‘[modelsummary](https://cran.r-project.org/package=modelsummary)’ or ‘[texreg](https://cran.r-project.org/package=texreg)’ instead, or *literally anything else*.

Answer (score 0):

How about not using dummies but the real within calculation for fixed effects? Try the `plm` package. In this way you don't have to remove your unit dummies.

````
---
title: "Stargazer"
author: "Author"
output: pdf_document
---

## Stargazer

```{r, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(stargazer)

# real within calculation from plm package
library(plm)
data("Produc", package = "plm")
fe_model <- plm(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp, data = Produc, model = "within")

stargazer(fe_model, type="text")
```
````